# use C code in C# project without Dll's

Tags: c#

I have read the other topics but there is apparently no way to do it,
is it possible to use C code in C# Project without using dll ?

Comment: Write your own compiler that can compile C and C# in the same assembly.

Comment: The C code has to be compiled into some kind of binary. It can be either library (dll) or an executable (exe). So you are leaving only the second option, which is just to run some external executables by the `C#` program.

Comment: Give us an example why you want to do this?

Comment: I would clarify why you want to do this and why you can't use a DLL. Depending on your needs and constraints, we might have drastically different answers. For example: Are you looking for ways to run existing C code from within .NET? Do you need to dynamically execute a small chunk of code typed in by an user? Your question is about to be closed. Don't worry about :) Just edit it to provide more detail and it'll go in a queue to be reopened. Good luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: that's right ! I want to use some of my functions written in C.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are defining "use" and "C code" but the basic answer is **No**. You certainly can't just include a C header file or call native C functions.

You *can* however write code that *looks* like C in C# (still using pointers and such), you just need to be in `unsafe` mode. Note that any C standard methods would not be available and some syntactic changes would be necessary if you were pasting in C source. This is also considered bad practice; you should be writing in normal C# 99.99999% of the time.

Comment: Well.. this "looks like C", is not very accurate...

Comment: @EugeneSh. What phrasing would you prefer, the question was slightly ambiguous as to what he meant by "C code"

Comment: I mean that even if you are in unsafe mode, you won't be able to just paste in a regular C code. The syntax is just different.

Comment: Theoretically there is a way. You can just write C code as a resource file then use some GCC to compile this at runtime into DLL then load it dynamically and make platform invoke calls. But It's stupid way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sure, I tried to clarify that. Feel free to suggest an edit if you have anything specific you think should be different.

Comment: @m.rogalski but that's still using a DLL, what the OP said not to do.

Comment: @Dispersia Yea, but you write all of the code in one "project" :D and as I said it's stupid way but kind of a funny way though.

Comment: thank you very much for you'r help, now i'm sure it's bad idea, I'll choose one of alternatives.